# How to query Olympians data from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I was able to query athletes data from DBpedia, or data about a specific sport (e.g. basketball)

Is there a way to retrieve Olympians data?

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you trying to figure out how to restrict your results to Olympians, rather than just athletes? Or you're looking for some particular Olympic information that regular athletes don't have?

Comment: Exactly, I want to restrict results to Olympians ..
I don't want data about all Athletes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBPedia includes a skos:broader hierarchy on Olympic athletes.  Therefore you can check whether an athlete is the subject of one of these terms.  For a start, try the following query:

```
SELECT ?
WHERE {
   ?olympicTerm skos:broader* <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Olympic_competitors> .
   ?person dct:subject ?olympicTerm .
}
```